# max min Dinkelbach algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am trying to implement the general form of the Dinkelbach algorithm in MATLAB. However, it is not so clear for me. The algorithm is showed in the image.[image]

My Question is the following:

What shall represent the maximum and minimum? are they `argmax` and `argmin` or the maximum and minimum values and for what?

I will be thankful if anyone could give me a simple explanation about how it works.

Comment: Please post text as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

mu is the maximum of values for the given functions and arguments x0, across all functions in your set (e.g. step 0 or step 3).

x=argmin() refers to the values of x which minimize e.g. max(f(x)-u*g(x)) (as in step 1), which means you probably have to do some function minimization here.